# Codeigniter htaccess not working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu-16.04, codeigniter-3

*This application biuld in Codeigniter Version = 3.1.3. when build this application work it properly with this htaccess file but today when i run this application & face this type of error.*

> When run my codeigniter website, htaccess file can't rewrite my
>   index.php url. so, requested URL was not found error shown.

**properly working url** => localhost/Magpie/index.php/Front_master/aboutus.html

**Error url** => localhost/Magpie/index.php/Front_master/aboutus.html

---

**Here is my htaccess code:**

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteBase /Magpie/
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Controller file: **Front_master.php**

```
<?php

    class Front_master extends CI_Controller {

      public $result = array();
      public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();

      //load models
      $this->result["getContact"] = $this->GetInformation->getContact();
      $this->result["getLogo"] = $this->GetInformation->getLogo();
      $this->result["getSlide"] = $this->GetInformation->getSlide();
      $this->result["getServices"] = $this->GetInformation->getServices();
      $this->result["getContent"] = $this->GetInformation->getContent();
      $this->result["getPropertyListing"] = $this->GetInformation->getPropertyListing();
      $this->result["getBestDeal"] = $this->GetInformation->getBestDeal();
      $this->result["getTeam"] = $this->GetInformation->getTeam();
    }

    public function index() {
      $data = array();

      $data['title'] = 'Home Page';
      $data['header'] = $this->load->view('frontview/header', $this->result, TRUE);
      $data['slider'] = $this->load->view('frontview/slider', $this->result, TRUE);
      $data['dashboard'] = $this->load->view('frontview/dashboard', $this->result, TRUE);
      $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('frontview/footer', '', TRUE);
      $this->load->view('frontview/master', $data);
    }

    public function aboutus() {
      $data = array();
      $data['title'] = 'About Us';
      $data['header'] = $this->load->view('frontview/header', $this->result, TRUE);
      $data['dashboard'] = $this->load->view('frontview/about_us', $this->result, TRUE);
      $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('frontview/footer', $this->result, TRUE);
      $this->load->view('frontview/master', $data);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y99NL.png)

Comment: what is the error u getting?

Comment: The requested URL /Magpie/Front_master/aboutus.html was not found on this server.

Comment: show your  code also

Comment: you may need this "AllowOverride All" in apache.conf file

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite try this command and restart your apache

Comment: why is there `.html` extension in your `url`

Comment: for add $config['url_suffix'] = '.html'; just alias of .php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this htaccess code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /Magpie/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**Step 2 :**

Remove index.php in codeigniter config

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**Step 3 :**

Allow overriding htaccess in Apache Configuration (Command)

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and edit the file & change to

```
AllowOverride All
```

for www folder

**Step 4 :**

Enabled apache mod rewrite (Command)

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

**Step 5 :**

Restart Apache (Command)

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and use this url:

localhost/Magpie/Front_master/aboutus

Comment: Not Work. Same Problem

Comment: what url you have use?

Comment: localhost/Magpie/Front_master/aboutus

Comment: have you change $config['index_page'] = ""; in config.php?

Comment: `$config['base_url']` Should NOT be empty. As it states in the comments for this setting in config.php "WARNING: You MUST set this value!"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is will come from the database issue. The error will show "*Expression #8 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'tappo_stage_db.Ratings.rating' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by*".Therefore you should want to run this command.

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```